# Code encapsulation of "TextField.For" in MudBlazor

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

I'm just moving from ASP.NET MVC razor to Blazor.

I'm trying to build a universal `CreateOrUpdateDialog` for all types.

Here is simple example code with a more complex sandbox (https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QkQHOCmBnTDeSuTp):

```
// What I want:
@foreach(var propertyInfo in model.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var label = propertyInfo.Name;
    var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(model);
    <MudTextField @bind-Value="value"     
                  Immediate="true"
                  Label="@label"/>
}
            
// Normal code:
<MudTextField @bind-Value="model.Name"                              
              For="@(() => model.Name)"
              Immediate="true"
              Label="Name" />
```

There are 2 problems:

1. How to deal with the `For`?

   Now if you click the 2nd email (normal code) and leave it with an empty value, there will be an error message; while there is nothing in the 1st email (what I want)
2. I don't think the bound "value" can be updated to property of the model (will name = "propertyInfo.Name" do the trick?).

Any help will be appreciated.

And: TextField api is here: https://dev.mudblazor.com/components/textfield#api

Comment: I believe that's not possible, you need to original reference of the object to bind to and AFAIK you can't get that using propertyinfo. You should probably tag this question as C#

Comment: Ohh，I did tag it as C# at the beginning. Half of my CreateDialog can be simplified if it works. @RBee